# Microsoft Access not overwriting when exporting a query to excel

Tags: ms-access, export-to-excel

I have an access dataset that has multiple queries. I update my linked excel tables and then export the queries again so I have access to the analysis I set up easily with updated data. The problem I am having is that sometimes when I export the query to excel it gives me a prompt warning me that it is going to overwrite the old file. I tell it to proceed and it runs through the export process but when I check the export file it is still the old file and not even the date modified column in windows explorer has changed. Some days certain queries have this problem and other days they all work. I do not have any clue why. I can delete the original file and run the export and it will work fine but this is a daily activity if not multiple times a day for multiple queries, manually deleting adds quite a bit of work and if I forget to delete it will possibly not export and then I am working with the wrong data. Is there anyway to fix this issue without getting into VBA which I have a very limited knowledge of.

Comment: Did someone else write the code to do this export? Are you able to paste the function with is not working in here? (preferably not the entire thing if it is long but just the part you think is the issue) It's hard to diagnose without seeing what the issues could be.

Comment: Use VBA to check for and then delete the existing file before doing the export. If you post up the existing export code I'm sure it would be simple to modify if you can't do it yourself.

Comment: I have been just right clicking on the query on the left under the all access objects list and selecting export -> excel and then selecting the old file. I did save all of my exports and wrote a macro that just runs each saved export but it does not overwrite sometimes with both methods.